# Adding Security Header

Tags: java, apache-axis, stub

I am trying to generate a security header in a Java Axis2 Client in the below format.

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Username>xxx</wsu:Username>
            <wsu:Password Type="wsse:PassowrdTest">xxx</wsu:Password>
        </wsu:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Below is my code so far:

```
SOAPHeaderElement wsseSecurity = new SOAPHeaderElement(
        new PrefixedQName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd","Security", "wsse"));         
wsseSecurity.setMustUnderstand(true);
wsseSecurity.setActor(null); 

SOAPElement sub =wsseSecurity.addChildElement("UsernameToken");
sub.setAttribute("wsu:Id", "UsernameToken-2");

SOAPElement userElement = sub.addChildElement("Username");
userElement.addTextNode("xxx"); 

SOAPElement pwdElement = sub.addChildElement("Password");
pwdElement.setAttribute("Type", "wsse:PasswordText");
pwdElement.addTextNode("xxx");

stub.setHeader(wsseSecurity);
```

Comment: My Code is not able to generate the expected format.Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you out. take a look:

```
private static final String cNODE_USRTOKEN = "UsernameToken";
private static final String cNODE_USERNAME = "Username";
private static final String cNODE_PASSWORD = "Password";
private String iUsername;
private String iPassword;
private static final Logger cTRACE = Logger.getLogger(UsernameTokenHandler.class.getName());

public Element getToken() 
{


    Element assertion = null;
    SOAPElement soapElement = null;

    try 
    {

        SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
        SOAPPart sOAPPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = sOAPPart.getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader(); 

        if (header==null) 
        {
            // no header yet, create one
            header = envelope.addHeader();
        }
        SOAPElement security = header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");



        Name tUserTokenElementName = envelope.createName(cNODE_USRTOKEN, "wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        SOAPElement tUserTokenElement = security.addChildElement(tUserTokenElementName);
        tUserTokenElement.removeNamespaceDeclaration("wsse");
        tUserTokenElement.addNamespaceDeclaration("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

        // user name child
        Name tUsernameElementName = envelope.createName(cNODE_USERNAME, "wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        SOAPElement tUsernameElement = tUserTokenElement.addChildElement(tUsernameElementName);
        tUsernameElement.removeNamespaceDeclaration("wsse");
        tUsernameElement.addTextNode(iUsername);

        // password child
        Name tPasswordElementName = envelope.createName(cNODE_PASSWORD, "wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        SOAPElement tPasswordElement = tUserTokenElement.addChildElement(tPasswordElementName);
        tPasswordElement.removeNamespaceDeclaration("wsse");
        tPasswordElement.addTextNode(iPassword);
        tPasswordElement.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");

        assertion = (Element) security;

        //printAssertion(assertion);
        //MessageElement samlElement = new MessageElement(assertion);
        //SAMLHandler.setAssertion((SOAPElement) samlElement);
        //soapElement = (SOAPElement) samlElement;

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        if (cTRACE.isLoggable(Level.SEVERE)) 
        {
            cTRACE.logp(Level.SEVERE,UsernameTokenHandler.class.getName(),"handleMessage", "Unable to add WSS credentials", e);
        }

        // stop processing
        return assertion;
    }

    // continue processing
    return assertion;
}
```